# Best practices multiple field validation with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, validation, knockout.js

I am looking for the best practices for practices multiple field validation.
Say I have two number input for min and max.
Where and how can I implement the logic checking min must <= max ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to do this. The first being jquery and writing a custom validator and the second is using koValidate and writing a custom validator as well.

Comment: Yep, these are both acceptable.  Knockout-Validation tends to stay closer to spirit of MVVM, where the view-model data is validated, whereas jQuery validation simply validates the UI.